# Spring Data ElasticSearch documentation on annotations etc

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and Spring Data ElasticSearch, and trying it out for a project. I went through the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/), but couldn't find anything on the annotations like `@MultiField`. Are these things documented somewhere else? I basically needed a getting started kind of guide and some reference documentation of all the available annotations, features etc.

Or, maybe, after I gain some knowledge on ElasticSearch, these annotations would be self explanatory?

Comment: There isn't much documentation on those annotations, but there are a few on-line examples like [this one](https://github.com/SpringDataElasticsearchDevs/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/entities/Article.java) that you can use to figure out how that works. Don't hesitate to ask specific questions if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, @Val. I'm trying it out. BTW, the comment by "dadoonet" [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spring-data-elasticsearch-with-es-standalone-server/48900/2) says that Spring Data ElasticSearch no more works with ElastixSearch 2.x releases. Not true, and it's in active development, right?

Comment: If you use Spring Data ES alone, then yes, but if you're going through Spring Boot, it has not yet been released to work with ES 2.x.

Comment: I see. If Spring Data ES alone is actively being developed, even if Spring Boot support isn't there, I won't mind. It is, right?

Comment: Correct. If you're including `spring-data-elasticsearch` directly in your project (i.e without going through `spring-boot-starters`), you'll be able to use ES 2.x safely.

Comment: Great. Also, [seems that](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-elasticsearch) Spring Boot 1.4 will be coming with the starter.

Comment: Yes, that's what everyone is waiting for ;)